# CentOS 7.3 audit2allow return "plural forms expression could be dangerous"

Tags: centos7, python, selinux, auditd

Hi I try to check audit2why or audit2allow but I get error:

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why 
plural forms expression could be dangerous
```

I have just installed latest CentOS from repos, using netinstall ISO. Also during install, I have selected PCI-DSS profile.

Even SELinux in permissive returns the same.

My OS:

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

My Packages:

```
# yum list | grep -i policycoreutils-python
policycoreutils-python.x86_64           2.5-11.el7_3                   @updates
# yum list | grep -i audit
audit.x86_64                            2.6.5-3.el7_3.1                @updates 
audit-libs.x86_64                       2.6.5-3.el7_3.1                @updates 
audit-libs-python.x86_64                2.6.5-3.el7_3.1                @updates 
audit-libs.i686                         2.6.5-3.el7_3.1                updates  
audit-libs-devel.i686                   2.6.5-3.el7_3.1                updates  
audit-libs-devel.x86_64                 2.6.5-3.el7_3.1                updates  
audit-libs-static.i686                  2.6.5-3.el7_3.1                updates  
audit-libs-static.x86_64                2.6.5-3.el7_3.1                updates  
globus-gram-audit.noarch                4.6-1.el7                      epel     
nodejs-nsp-audit-shrinkwrap.noarch      1.0.3-2.el7                    epel     
rsyslog-mmaudit.x86_64                  7.4.7-16.el7                   base
```

Locale:

```
# locale
LANG=lt_LT.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="lt_LT.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

what else could be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added LANG=C before a command.